# Translate errors side server with ngx-translate

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm programming an application with angular 7, net core and I'm using the package ngx-translate for to translate in the client side https://github.com/ngx-translate/core. The problem is, I have a dynamic code in the catches in the controller for to handler errors of concurrency and unique key, then, I handle the specific error and I show it with a toast. The problem is: how can I translate this errors with ngx-translate?

**ProductController.cs**

In the first catch, we have errors of unique key, in the second catch we have concurrency error.

```cs
[HttpPut("{id}")] // /api/product/4
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody]ProductFormResource productFormResource, int id)
{
  try
  {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return BadRequest(ModelState);

    if (await _productCore.Update(id, productFormResource))
      return Ok();
  }
  catch (DbUpdateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx && (sqlEx.Number == 2601 || sqlEx.Number == 2627))
  {
    ConfigureMessageExceptionUniqueKey(productFormResource, ex, out string messageUK);
    return BadRequest(messageUK);
  }
  catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
  {
    var databaseEntry = ex.Entries.Single().GetDatabaseValues();
    if (databaseEntry == null)
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. The register was deleted by another user.");
    else
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, string.Concat("The record you attempted to edit ", "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The ", "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database ", "have been displayed."));
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      _logger.LogError($"Fail saving data. (Updating) {ex.Message}");
   }

   return BadRequest($"Fail saving data. (Updating)");
}

private void ConfigureMessageExceptionUniqueKey(ProductFormResource product, DbUpdateException ex, out string messageUK)
{
  string[] keys = { "Description", "Code" };
  messageUK = "";
  if (ex.InnerException != null)
  {
    if (ex.InnerException.Message.Contains(keys[0]))
    messageUK = $"There is already {product.Description}. Cannot save a value duplicate in Description.";
    if (ex.InnerException.Message.Contains(keys[1]))
    messageUK = $"There is already {product.Code}. Cannot save a value duplicate in Code.";
  }
}
```

**ProductService**

I call the server and handle any error

```
put(id, productPut): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.put(`${this.productEndPoint}/${id}`, productPut)
      .pipe(tap(m => console.log('put')), catchError(this.handleError));
}

handleError(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // server-side error
      console.log(error)
      errorMessage = `${error.error}\nError Code: ${error.status}`;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
}
```

**product-form.component.ts**

I show the error in toast

```
onSubmit() {
    var result$ = (this.product.id) ? this.productService.put(this.product.id, this.product) :
      this.productService.post(this.product);
    result$.subscribe(mt => {
        this.toastrService.success('Data saved successfully!', 'Good!', {closeButton: true});
        this.router.navigate([`/inventory-product-list/`]);
      },
      err => { this.toastrService.error(err, 'An error has ocurred!', { closeButton: true }); }
    );
  }
```

Some idea of how to translate those messages? Thanks for your comments,